# Sending Bulk emails from asp.net website through shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, shared-hosting

I am using gmail server settings to send emails for my asp.net website. Since there is a limitation on number of mails sent per day and limitations on sending to number of users, I cant use this service for long. Even If I use an idea to make sure I use multiple id's to send thousands of emails it will still not work.

I am taking care of all norms of subscribe and unsubscribe options, so that only registered users will receive mails.

I need to build a system which send mails accross **thousands of emails * thousands of users per day.** . I think this is possible, as emailers in twitter,facebook, orkut, linkeden work on same basis. Many of them use MailChimp Email Service.

But I am hosting my website on shared hosting (www.crystaltech.com) rather than dedicated server (Host Provider suggested me to go to dedicated server for my mail requirement). This host provider charges a lot to me if I include a dll, so I am not able to use dll. Is there any I can send bulk emails without using a dedicated server or dll.(Will use it in only in worst case scenario).My host providers said that they will be able to give service of sending only 800 mails per day. Are there any api providers for that. I have already checked with http://www.mailchimp.com/ and http://www.campaignmonitor.com/.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that most providers limit their infrastructure in order to avoid spammers. The easiest method would be to check with a company that can provide you the service you need to send the many emails you need.

As a sidenote, the websites you mentioned send those many emails because they run their own email servers who are not limited in any way in the amount of emails they can send. This kind of infrastructure is very expensive so unless you really need those capabilities, I believe your best bet would be to get a third party to send those emails for you.

Comment: thanks Kiranu, If you know any such could you please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

This is all determined by your hosting provider.  If they say that they will only give you unlimited outbound emails on a dedicated server then that's what you'll have to have.